# How to convert the string uppercase to lowercase without using inbuilt function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to convert the string uppercase to lowercase without using inbuilt function in JavaScript.

Convert the upper case to lower case without using any inbuilt method in JavaScript.
I have one solution

```
var testCase = 'HELLO WORLD';
var length = 0;
var finalAnswer = '';
var answer = [];
while (testCase[length] !==
    undefined) {
    length++;
}
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    answer.push(testCase[i]);
}
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (testCase[i] == 'A')
        answer[i] = 'a';
    else if (testCase[i] == 'B')
        answer[i] = 'b'
    else if (testCase[i] == 'C')
        answer[i] = 'c'
    else if (testCase[i] == 'D')
        answer[i] = 'd'
        .
        .
        .
    else if (testCase[i] == 'Y')
        answer[i] = 'y'
    else if (testCase[i] == 'Z')
        answer[i] = 'z'
}
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

    finalAnswer = finalAnswer + answer[i];
}
console.log(finalAnswer)
```

Give some better solution.

Comment: Whats the use case of that? The built-in functions will most likely be a lot quicker than your implementation then. Also "Give some better solution" is very bad. We aren't here to code for you, we are here to help you.

Comment: Assuming the final answer will be displayed on a screen using HTML, you may want to look at [text-transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform) of CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) and [`charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) to convert from `uppercase` to `lowercase` without using any method

**`one-liner solution`**

```
const result = testCase
  .split("")
  .map((c) =>
    c.charCodeAt() >= 65 && c.charCodeAt() <= 90
      ? String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt() + 32)
      : c
  )
  .join("");
```

```js
var testCase = "HELLO WORLD";

const result = [];
for (let c of testCase) {
  if (c.charCodeAt() >= 65 && c.charCodeAt() <= 90) 
    result.push(String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt() + 32));
  else result.push(c);
}

console.log(result.join(""));
```